# Bulk Changing Application Icons on System

Tags: finder, applications, dock, icon

So the question is pretty straight forward. I've disabled SIP (System Integrity Protection) and I am able to use the "copy paste" method, described in numerous tutorials, successfully to change my Application Icons. I'm wondering however if there is a folder where all the Application Icons are stored. I know that the Trash Icons and the Finder Icons are located at `System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources` and that I'm able to for all intensive purposes "click and drag" the new trash and finder icons to this folder and it update the icons accordingly.

Is there a central location where all Application Icons are stored so that I can click and drag all 50 of my 'new' icons to a folder and then restart the dock app to refresh the icons?

Comment: Short answer: no. Icons are stored within the individual application.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the input, would like to see how other people answer though! I'm sure there IS a way, but it might not be short, and thats ok.

Comment: Short answer of **other** people is still: no. There is **NO** way. The application icons are all stored in .../%application%.app/Contents/Resources/ even the Finder.icns: /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/. You might create an AppleScript which replaces the .icns files though: if \*.icns file exist in source folder search for \*.app and replace its \*.app/Contents/Resources/\*.icns with the one in source folder.

Comment: @klanomath Close. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

@klanomath is close, but you actually *can* bulk change the icon. While the .icns file is stored within the application, it's referenced in an .xml file known as `info.plist` inside the Contents folder of every app. There's a string `CFBundleIconFile` with specifies the name of the .icns file inside the Resources folder.

While simply finding every .icns file and changing it would probably work in most cases, it's not the best practice. While it's rare for .icns files to be used for anything other than application icons, some app bundles include multiple side apps. This method minimizes risk.

If you'd like, I'll gladly assist in building an app to fit your renaming needs.